# What is the most “genuinely Buddhist” kind of mindfulness?

Tags: mindfulness

I’d like to hear some reflections on mindfulness. I’m not talking here about meditation on the three marks or any kind of visualization, but mindfulness.

I am quoting here from B. Allan Wallace’s *The Attention Revolution*.

> [One] approach views mindfulness as nondiscriminating,
>   moment-to-moment ‘bare awareness’ [and the other] characterizes
>   mindfulness as bearing in mind the object of attention, the state of
>   not forgetting, not being distracted, and not floating.

Which one of these is the most “genuinely Buddhist” kind of mindfulness?

Comment: See Tse-fu Kuan's Mindfulness in early buddhism" for a comprehensive treatment of mindfulness in the pali canon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at this article which describes [The Noble Eightfold Path](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html),

- [Chapter VI: Right Mindfulness (Samma Sati)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html#ch6) talks about "bare attention"
- [Chapter VII: Right Concentration (Samma Samadhi)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html#ch7) talks about "centering the mind on an object"

So I think they're both Buddhist, but one is called "mindfulness" and the other "concentration".

Comment: I'm looking forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

> “And what is the faculty of sati? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, is mindful, highly meticulous, remembering & able to call to mind even things that were done & said long ago. (And here begins the satipatthana formula:) He remains focused on the body in & of itself — ardent, alert, & mindful — putting aside greed & distress with reference to the world. He remains focused on feelings in & of themselves... the mind in & of itself... mental qualities in & of themselves — ardent, alert, & mindful — putting aside greed & distress with reference to the world.”

SN 48.10

You could give a read to  *Mindfulness Defined by Thanissaro Bhikkhu* 
at http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/mindfulnessdefined.html

Comment: You seem to be going with the "mindfulness as nondiscriminating, moment-to-moment ‘bare awareness’" as the most "genuine" (I'm not shure my term "genuine" is a very good one, though)